# '@' in file names and 'gf' (go to file)

Tags: command

Vim/Neovim (this is an issue in both as far as I can tell) does not seem to like files with '@' in the name, even though I have `isfname` is set to the default, which is `@,48-57,/,.,-,_,+,,,#,$,%,~,=`, which makes me think that this all should work. Steps to reproduce:

```
echo "foo" > /tmp/bar@file
echo "/tmp/bar@file" | vim -u NONE -
```

The `gf` command will not go to the file, saying `E447: Can't find file "/tmp/bar" in path`. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Am I missing something here?

Yes, as written in `:h 'isfname'`:

> If the character is '@', all characters where isalpha() returns TRUE
>   are included.  Normally these are the characters a to z and A to Z,
>   plus accented characters.  To include '@' itself use "@-@".

So `@` in `isfname`, `iskeyword` etc. actually means "all alphas", not literal "@". And you still need to add `set isfname+=@-@` to your vimrc.

Comment: thanks for RTFM'ing for me :)